# How to control arduino + cylon with web frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, cylon.js

Im looking for a tutorial for controlling the arduino from a web frontend. 
I already have a cylon/arduino program running.

Do I need [api-http?](https://github.com/hybridgroup/cylon-api-http) I can't find any documentation on what i'm trying to do. What I want to do is lets say toggle a LED with an HTML button. I tried using the browserify tool but I got some errors. I'm not even sure If for what I want to do I need browserify. (Will post all the info if needed)

Thanks!

*Note: I have experience with the MEAN stack.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im answering my question because I feel that Mike Zhang's answer didn't provide enough info.

So if you have a cylon program copy and paste that to the bottom of your node `app.js`

For what I wanted to do I just used the express generator and added a link to the ejs that would toggle a variable in my `routes/index` which I would require in my `app.js` and then added an if statement to my robot code to only run if the variable is true.

Answer (score 1):

From web front send ajax request to backend. At backend serve when it get the ajax request try to call cylon api to control your robot.

Comment: Ok I did this.  But know how do I have the nodejs localhost server and the cylon script.js running simultaneous ?

Comment: You mean Cylon.JS? Using require('cylon')  at the server.js and put the control code  into you ajax handle method function , [Control code example](http://cylonjs.com/documentation/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

what you need is cylon-api-socketio.. You can create an html page with your button and whatever controls you want..In your robot code (cylonjs script) create custom "Commands". Enable the socket io server in the script.. Then Those commands can then be invoked on button action  in your html page through the socket io api.. cylon-api-socketio actually exposes a large number of commands for each of its drivers. You may not even have to create custom commands. So it would be trivial to invoke the appropiate command.

[How To Connect with the SocketIO API](http://cylonjs.com/documentation/api/socket-io/)

Comment: Well It works without sockeitIO, And I don't need or want real time anything.